# How does mutate_all(.funs=~./sum(x)) work?

Tags: r, dplyr, sum, plyr

I used this code to calculate relative abundance (cell/total of column) of a table I had. I don't understand how the . and ~ functions work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The construct `~./sum(x)` is technically a special type of R object called a *formula*

```r
class(~./sum(x))
#> [1] "formula"
```

However, in tidyverse functions such as `mutate_all`, this formula is taken and converted into a *lambda function*, which is an anonymous function (i.e. a function that isn't named and is written in place as a parameter passed in a call to another function).

Internally, the formula is converted into a function with `rlang::as_function`. Suppose we wanted to write a function that just adds two to a variable. In base R we might write

```
add_two <- function(var){
  return(var + 2)
}

add_two(5)
#> [1] 7
```

In the tidyverse, we can use a formula as shorthand for this function, where the `.` becomes a shorthand for "the variable that was passed as a first argument to the function":

```
add_two <- rlang::as_function(~ . + 2)

add_two(5)
#> [1] 7
```

In functions such as `mutate_all`, the formula will automatically be passed through `rlang::as_function`, so if we wanted to add two to each column in our data frame, instead of writing:

```
mutate_all(.funs= function(var) {return(var + 2);})
```

we could write

```
mutate_all(.funs=~.+2)
```

In your case, the formula `~./sum(x)` is effectively transformed into

```
function(var) {
  return(var / sum(x))
}
```

where x has to exist either as a column in your data frame or a variable in the calling environment.

The reasons for having it this way are that it saves typing and shortens lines of code. Inserting a function within a call to another function often leads to messy and poorly formatted code. This shorthand method helps to prevent that.

You can read more about anonymous functions and how they are used in the tidyverse [here](https://coolbutuseless.github.io/2019/03/13/anonymous-functions-in-r-part-1/)

Answer (score 0):

mutate_all applies the function in .funs to all values. Each value (.) is divided by the sum(x), to get you the "relative abundance" which is essentially the fraction of the total value, which is the sum(x). You can think of ~ as a "function of". So you are saying each cell in the dataframe is a function of itself divided by the overall sum.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose we have this dataset:

```
dataset <- data.frame(a = c(1,2,3,4),
                      b = c(2,3,4,5),
                      c = c(3,4,5,6))
```

And you want to divide all vectors by the total (ie. for vector a = 1/10, 2/10, 3/10, 4/10). To avoid writing for all variables, you can use `mutate_all`, and then a lambda using `.funs`which says make a function that divides all values in each vector represented by the dot by the sum of all values in that vector.

```
dataset %>% mutate_all(.funs = ~./sum(.))
```

Hope this helps.